# Can not figure out how to fix code... gone beyond my comprehension

Tags: java, arrays, user-interface

I have a code that I have been attempting to create. Thus far it will not compile and run, the array is off and the GUI will not work. I am lost as far as fixing this code goes. I am afraid I will have to start over and be lost again. Here is my mess if anyone can help me...

```
/*
* To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
* and open the template in the editor.
*/
package mobile.phones;

/**
*
* @author Parents
*/
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.PopupMenu;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class MobilePhones {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

}
private String ItemNumber; //item # of product
private String ProductName; //product name
private String Department; //department name
private double UnitStock; //units in stock
private double ItemPrice; //Price per unit
private double InventoryValue; //The dollar value of the inventory in stock
private double CalculateInventory; //The total value of all of the inventory in stock
private double value;
private double UnitPrice;
int getValue;
private MobilePhones myPhone;
/**
 *
 */

//constructor
public MobilePhones (String item, String product, String department, double units,      double price) {
    String unit = null;
    ItemNumber = unit;
    ProductName = product;
    String dept = null;
Department = dept;
    double stock = 0;
    UnitStock = stock;
    double Price = price;
} //end constructor

//getter and setter methods for MobilePhones

public void setItemNumber (String item) { String unit = null;
//setter for item number
    this.ItemNumber = unit;
} //end setter item number

public String getItemNumber() { //getter for item number
    return ItemNumber;
} //end getter item number

public void setProductName (String product) { //setter for product name
    this.ProductName = product;
} //end setter product name

public String getProductName() { //getter for product name
    return ProductName;
} //end getter product name

public void setDepartment (String department) { String dept = null;
//setter for department name
    this.Department = dept;
} //end setter department name

public String getDepartment() { //getter for department name
    return Department;
} //end getter department name

public void setUnitStock (double units) { double stock = 0;
//setter for units in stock
    this.UnitStock = stock;
} //end setter units in stock

public double getUnitStock() { //getter for units in stock
    return UnitStock;
} //end getter units in stock

public void setUnitPrice (double price) { //setter for unit price
    this.UnitPrice = price;
} //end setter unit price

public double getUnitPrice() { //getter for unit price
    return UnitPrice;
} //end getter for unit price

//calculate inventory value
public double getInventoryValue(){
    return UnitStock * UnitPrice;
}//end calculate inventory value

public void setCalculateInventory (double value){
    this.CalculateInventory = value;
}

public double getCalculateInventory(Phone[] myPhones){
    double revenue = 0.0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        revenue = getInventoryValue();
        {

    myPhones[0] = new Phone ("0001");
    myPhones[1] = new Phone ("0002");
    myPhones[2] = new Phone ("0003");
    myPhones[3] = new Phone ("0004");
    myPhones[4] = new Phone ("0005");

    //output
        System.out.println("Product Number: \t\t" + myPhones[i].getItemNumber());

        System.out.println("Item Name: \t\t\t" + myPhones[i].getProductName());

        System.out.println("Number of Items currently in Stock: \t" +     myPhones[i].getUnitsStock());

        System.out.println("Cost per Unit: \t\t$%.2f\n" + myPhones[i].getUnitPrice());            

        System.out.printf("Total Value of Inventory is: \t$%.2f\n", revenue);

        System.out.println();

    } // end output
    return 0.0;

/**
*
* @author Parents
*/

}
    return 0;
}
private static class Phone {

    public Phone() {
    }

    private Phone(String string) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body  of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    private String getItemNumber() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    private String getProductName() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    private String getUnitsStock() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    private String getUnitPrice() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
}
class SmartPhone extends MobilePhones{
    private String MobileOS;
    private double restockingfee;
    double rate = 0.05;
    int getValue;
    public SmartPhone( String item, String product, String department, double units,    double price, String MobileOS )
{
super(item, product, department, units, price);
this.MobileOS = MobileOS;
}

public String getMobileOS() {
return MobileOS;
}
public void setMobileOS(String MobileOS) {
this.MobileOS = MobileOS;
}
public double getValue()
{
return getValue() * 0.05;
}
public double getRestockingFee()
{
return getValue() * 0.05;
}
    @Override
    public String toString()
{
String formatString = "MobilePhone: %s";
formatString += "Restocking Fee: $%.2f";
formatString = String.format( formatString, MobilePhones,
getValue() * 0.05 );
return( formatString + super.toString() );
}      
}
import java.awt.GridLayout
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent
import java.awt.event.ActionListener

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

/**
 *
 */
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public final class MobilePhonesGUI extends JFrame {

JTextField itemNumber = new JTextField();
JTextField name = new JTextField();
JTextField unitsInStock = new JTextField();
JTextField unitPrice = new JTextField();
JTextField valueOfInventory = new JTextField();
JTextField restockingFee = new JTextField();

JButton next = new JButton("Next Product");
JButton prior = new JButton("Prior Product");

JTextField valueOfEntireInventory = new JTextField();

private MobilePhones[] MobilePhones = new MobilePhones[] {};
private int productIndex = 0;

private void showNext() {
    if (productIndex < products.length - 1) {
        productIndex++;
        updateGUI();
    }
}

private void showPrior() {
    if (productIndex > 0) {
        productIndex--;
        updateGUI();
    }
}

public void updateGUI() {
    Product currentProduct = products[productIndex];

    itemNumber.setText(currentProduct.getItemNumber().toString());
    name.setText(currentProduct.getName());
    unitsInStock.setText(currentProduct.getUnitsInStock().toString());
    unitPrice.setText(currentProduct.getUnitPrice().toString());
    valueOfInventory.setText(currentProduct.getValueOfInventory()
            .toString());
    restockingFee.setText(currentProduct.getRestokingFee().toString());

    valueOfEntireInventory.setText(calcValueOfEntireInventory().toString());

}

public Double calcValueOfEntireInventory() {
    double value = 0;

    for (Product p : products) {
        value += p.getValueOfInventory();
    }

    return value;
}

public MobilePhonesGUI(Product[] products) {
    super();
    this.products = products;

    setTitle("Inventory GUI");
    setBounds(0, 0, 400, 300);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    createGUI();
    pack();

    prior.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            showPrior();
        }
                    throw new ("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated     methods, choose Tools | Templates.

            });
            }
    next.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            showNext();
        }
                        return null;
    });

    MobilePhonesGUI();
}

private void createGUI(PopupMenu valueOfEntireInventory, PopupMenu next, PopupMenu  prior, PopupMenu restockingFee, PopupMenu valueOfInventory, PopupMenu unitPrice, PopupMenu  unitsInStock, PopupMenu name, PopupMenu itemNumber) {
    JPanel productPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 2, 5, 5));
        Component add;
        add = productPanel.add(new JLabel("Item Number:"));
    productPanel.add(itemNumber);

    productPanel.add(new JLabel("Product Name:"));
    productPanel.add(name);

    productPanel.add(new JLabel("Units In Stock:"));
    productPanel.add(unitsInStock);

    productPanel.add(new JLabel("Unit Price:"));
    productPanel.add(unitPrice);

    productPanel.add(new JLabel("Value of Inventory:"));
    productPanel.add(valueOfInventory);

    productPanel.add(new JLabel("Restocking Fee (5%):"));
    productPanel.add(restockingFee);

    productPanel.add(prior);
    productPanel.add(next);

    productPanel.add(new JLabel("Value of Entire Inventory:"));
    productPanel.add(valueOfEntireInventory);

    JPanel inventoryPanel = new JPanel();
    inventoryPanel.add(productPanel);

    setContentPane(inventoryPanel);
}

/**
     *
     * @param args
     */
    public void main(String[] args) {
    Product[] products;
        products = new Product[] { new Product(1, "Mouse", 100, 5.0),
              new Product(2, "Keyboard", 130, 15.9),
              new Product(3, "Notebook", 10, 800.5),
              new Product(4, "Memory Key", 20, 20.5) };

    new InventoryGUI(products).setVisible(true);
}

 }
```

Comment: Improve your comprehension. Don't expect us to be your debuggers.

Comment: Are there any errors? It may help if you post those as well.

Comment: Start a new project and add your code one part at a time. Fix any and every problem before adding the next part.

Answer (score -1):

One thing I noticed is that you didn't declare the size of the array before trying to use it. If you know that you only are going to have five phones in your getClaculateInventory method you need to declare the size of the phone array.

```
public double getCalculateInventory(Phone[] myPhones){
    double revenue = 0.0;
    myPhones = new Phone[5];
```

If you want you could even use the for loop to fill the array with the values you want.